Handbook for intermediary level ESL to talk to babies in English
My wife is an intermediary ESL speaker (she didn't take any standardized test, I guess her level is ~B1-B2). She is now interacting with our ~one-year old baby ~90% in mother tongue and ~10% in English.
I am now exploring ways to increase the portion of English use. I am wondering if anyone can recommend some books to teach adults(i.e., my wife) to communicate with kids in English. The book should be about practical language use, not parenting theories. For example, the book should explain (to ESL parents) how to say "we need to change your diaper" / "let's take a nap now" / "Be quiet on a bus"/etc.
Any recommendations?

Do you have a particular concern with your child's exposure to your native tongue (which I assume is English?) Are you in an English speaking country? Do you spend time with your wife and child communicating in English? Is your child attending a childcare setting out of the house?

I don't understand the goal of the question. Children do not learn a language as defined in a book. They learn a language based on the interaction they have with the people around them. If your wife speaks English a certain way (whether it be an accent or particular grammatical quirk), your child will learn to understand her because it has no preconceived notion of what English should be. If anything, native English speakers will probably struggle with her more than your child will, because they start from their academic understanding of the language as prescribed, which your child doesn't.

This is a frame challenge, but which language do you use to interact with the child?
The easiest, most common and to my knowledge also most successful approach to bilingualism is to have one language associated to each parent (or other person frequently interacting with the child). So you wife speaks her native language (exclusively when talking to the baby), you speak English to the baby and that's it, you child will grow up to be bilingual without any additional training or further adaptation needed.

yes I am aware of the so-called OPOL model, the problem is, my wife would need to talk to kindergarten/school staff in English. So I am thinking she may also need to practice a bit herself.

@D.J.Elkind: OPOL is not meant to be a prohibition on your wife speaking the other language ever in her life, or to maintain a facade in front of the child as if she only speaks one language. OPOL indicates what the driving language between a specific parent and their child should be. Your child seeing your wife speak English to another person is not going to undo the OPOL learning process. Similarly, OPOL does not dictate what language the parents use to speak to each other either.

The most important consideration should be the bonding and communication between mother and child.  Your wife should be practicing her English at school, in the stores, with neighbors, etc.  Home should be a haven where she can express herself best, and let your child learn the full range of communication, regardless of language.  At home your wife should sing, read-aloud books, tell jokes, and everything else in her native language.
Assuming that English is the dominant language where you live, your child will have plenty of opportunities to learn English, especially at such a young age.  And there are many other ways for your wife to improve her English. For example, listening to the radio, visiting neighbors, or working as an assistant in a child-care setting, where vocabulary is limited.
I say all this having both been raised bilingually, and now raising my own children bilingually.
